# C# converting string to int goes wrong

Tags: c#, string, int, converters

I have a `string` that contains numbers, like so:

```
string keyCode = "1200009990000000000990";
```

Now I want to get the number on position 2 as `integer`, which I did like so:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(keyCode[1]);
```

But instead of getting `2`, I get `50`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think instead of keycode[1], using keycode.Substring(1,1).

Comment: As explained in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Convert.ToInt32(char)`: `Converts the value of the specified Unicode character to the equivalent 32-bit signed integer.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

50 is the ascii code for char '2'. 0->48, 1->49 etc....

You can do

```
int number = keyCode[1]-'0';
```

Answer (score 4):

You observed that when you do `int n = Convert.ToInt32( '2' );` you get `50`.  That's correct.

Apparently, you did not expect to get `50`, you expected to get `2`.  That's what's not correct to expect.

It is not correct to expect that `Convert.ToInt32( '2' )` will give you `2`, because then what would you expect if you did `Convert.ToInt32( 'A' )` ?

A character is not a number.  But of course, inside the computer, everything is represented as a number.  So, there is a mapping that tells us what number to use to represent each character.  Unicode is such a mapping, ASCII is another mapping that you may have heard of.  These mappings stipulate that the character `'2'` corresponds to the number `50`, just as they stipulate that the character `'A'` corresponds to the number `65`.

`Convert.ToInt32( char c )` performs a very rudimentary conversion, it essentially *reinterprets* the character as a number, so it allows you to see what number the character corresponds to.  But if from `'2'` you want to get `2`, that's not the conversion you want.

Instead, you want a more complex conversion, which is the following: `int n = Int32.Parse( keyCode.SubString( 1, 1 ) );`

Answer (score 3):

Well, You got 50 because it is the ascii code of `2`.

You are getting it because you are pointing to a `char` and when c# converts a `char` to an `int` it gives back its ascii code. You should use instead `int.Parse` which takes a `string`.

```
int.Parse(keyCode[1].ToString());
```

or

```
int.Parse(keyCode.Substring(1,1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
int number = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(keyCode[1]);
```

The cast is needed because [Char.GetNumericValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getnumericvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returns a double.

Answer (score 0):

As Ofir said, another method is `int number = int.Parse(keyCode[1].ToString())`.

This command can be explained like this: `int` is shorthand for `Int32`, which contains a `Parse(string)` method. `Parse` only works if the input is a string that contains only numbers, so it's not always the best to use unless `TryParse` (the method that checks whether you can parse a string or not) has been invoked and returns `true`, but in this case, since your input string is *always* a number, you can use `Parse` without using `TryParse` first. `keyCode[1]` actually implicitly converts keyCode to a `char[]` first so that it can retrieve a specific index, which is why you need to invoke `ToString()` on it before you can parse it.

This is my personal favorite way to convert a `string` or `char` to an `int`, since it's pretty easy to make sense of once you understand the conversions that are performed both explicitly and implicitly. If the string to convert isn't static, it may be better to use a different method, since an `if` statement checking whether it can be parsed or a `try` makes it take longer to code and execute than one of the other solutions.